# Is it possible to export a video object detection model from google vertex ai?

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

I have trained a video object detection model on google cloud vertex ai but i dont know how to export and download it. I need to do it through nodejs or curl. Anyone knows how?

I tried using their api https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/samples/aiplatform-export-model-sample#aiplatform_export_model_sample-nodejs and https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/export/export-edge-model but both cases fail. First gives a "cannot use outputConfig before its initialized and the second (using curl) returns a 404 not found. This is my code:

```
async function exportModel(userID) {

    let [response] = await modelServiceClient.listModels({ parent: modelServiceClient.locationPath(PROJECT_ID, REGION) })

    CURL VERSION

    const name = modelServiceClient.modelPath(PROJECT_ID, REGION, response[0].name.split('/').pop())

    const json = {
        "outputConfig": {
            "exportFormatId": "tflite",
            "artifactDestination": {
                "outputUriPrefix": `gs://${BUCKET_NAME}/${userID}/`
            }
        }
    }

    axios.post(`https://${REGION}-aiplatform.googleapis.com/v1/${name}`, json)
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error)
        })

    COMMENTED OUT NODEJS VERSION

    /*const outputConfig = {
        exportFormatId: 'tf-saved-model',
        gcsDestination: {
            outputUriPrefix: `gs://${BUCKET_NAME}/${userID}/`,
        },
    }

    [response] = await modelServiceClient.exportModel({
        name,
        outputConfig
    })

    const result = await response.promise()

    console.log(result)*/

}
```